# Echo Code into a File using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a VBScript which I want to use to echo the code of another VBScript into an output file.

However, I am unable to write some of the characters to the output file using this method.

If I use the command line method:

```
cmd.exe /c "@echo "hello"">output.vbs
```

This works and the string: "hello" is written to the output file.

However, when I do the same using a VBScript, it does not work.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "%comspec% /c ""@echo ""hello"">output.vbs"
```

So, is there a way I can echo it into another file retaining the double quotes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoting is wrong.

Change this:

```
objShell.Run "%comspec% /c ""@echo ""hello"">output.vbs"
```

into this:

```
objShell.Run "%comspec% /c @echo ""hello"">output.vbs"
```